# composer your requirements could not be resolved fedesas/laravel-mail-css-inliner

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

So I am trying to install version 1.3 of  fedesas/laravel-mail-css-inliner as a dependency of my own package and I am getting the following error (using laravel 4.2):

```
 Problem 1
    - bgarrison25/beautymail 1.0.6 requires fedeisas/laravel-mail-css-inliner 1.3 -> satisfiable by fedeisas/laravel-mail-css-inliner[1.3].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.3
    - Installation request for bgarrison25/beautymail 1.0.6 -> satisfiable by bgarrison25/beautymail[1.0.6].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.1
    - fedeisas/laravel-mail-css-inliner 1.3 requires illuminate/support 4.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.10|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.11|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.12|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.14|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.15|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.17|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.18|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.19|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.21|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.23|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.24|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.26|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.27|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.29|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.3|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.4|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.5|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.7|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.9|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.13, v4.2.14, v4.2.15, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
```

This is my composer.json file:

```
{
        "name": "laravel/laravel",
        "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
        "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
        "license": "MIT",
        "require": {
                "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
                "way/generators": "~2.0",
                "greggilbert/recaptcha": "1.*",
                "bgarrison25/beautymail": "1.0.6"
        },
        "autoload": {
                "classmap": [
                        "app/commands",
                        "app/controllers",
                        "app/models",
                        "app/database/migrations",
                        "app/database/seeds",
                        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
                ],
                "psr-0": {
                    "MSHLibrary": "app/"
                }
        },
        "scripts": {
                "post-install-cmd": [
                        "php artisan clear-compiled",
                        "php artisan optimize"
                ],
                "post-update-cmd": [
                        "php artisan clear-compiled",
                        "php artisan optimize"
                ],
                "post-create-project-cmd": [
                        "php artisan key:generate"
                ]
        },
        "config": {
                "preferred-install": "dist"
        },
        "minimum-stability": "stable",
        "require-dev": {
                "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4"
        }
}
```

Comment: Nice post but a little bit messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just require

"fedeisas/laravel-mail-css-inliner": "dev-master#4d3e2f65f1b2316451e1937d6f741913fafb890b"

Answer (score 1):

`fedeisas/laravel-mail-css-inliner 1.3 requires illuminate/support 4.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].`

Here's your problem, `fedeisas/laravel-mail-css-inliner` require `illuminate/support` v4.1.x while you are using Laravel v4.2.x

Comment: I thought `illuminate/support` v4.x supported laravel 4.2. I thought it wasn't until v5.x that it dropped support

Comment: `fedeisas/laravel-mail-css-inliner 1.3 requires illuminate/support 4.1.*` and not `illuminate/support 4.*`.